# How to customize form field based on user roles in Symfony2/3?

Tags: symfony, formbuilder, symfony-2.8

**Is there a correct way to customize a form depending on the role of the user that requests it?**

My scenario is pretty simple: I need to hide some fields if the user has not the `ROLE_ADMIN` granted. I tried to avoid the field display on Twig, but

```
  {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
              {{form_row(form.field)}}
  {% endif %}
```

not works, because the form builder bypass this check.

Symfony version: **2.8.2**

**EDIT**

Thanks to the @Rooneyl [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433667/1977778) I've found the solution:

At first, you need to add the 'role' key to the options parameter. So, in the configureOptions() `$options['role']` is always *ROLE_USER*.

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Ticket',
        'role' => 'ROLE_USER'
    ));
}
```

Then in the controller you have to pass the `getRoles()` array:

```
$user_roles = $this->getUser()->getRoles();
$form = $this->createForm('MyBundle\Form\TicketType', $ticket, array('role' => $user_roles));
```

Comment: have updated the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an option passed to the form builder to say what elements are generated.
This way you can change the content and validation that gets done (using validation_groups).
For example, your controller (assuming roles is an array);
you controller;

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyType(), $user, ['role' => $this->getUser()->getRoles()]);
```

And your form:

```
<?php 
namespace AppBundle\Form\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType,
    Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface,
    Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MyType extends AbstractType 
{
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => ['create'],
            'role' => ['ROLE_USER']
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // dump($options['roles']);
        if (in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $options['role'])) {
            // do as you want if admin
            $builder
                ->add('name', 'text');
        } else {
            $builder
                ->add('supername', 'text');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_my_form';
    }

}
```

Comment: When I try to use the options parameter Symfony returns this error: `The option "role" does not exist.`. Why?

Comment: I think the `$options['role']` has to be `getUser()->getRoles()`.

Comment: The code may not be complete, I'm mobile so can't test it at the moment. I will run it and give a complete solution in a bit, but the theory it is sound.

Comment: The main problem seems to be related to the `$options` array. It's not possible to add the `role` key.

Comment: Rooneyl's example uses `roles` both in the `$options` array and in the `configureOptions()` function - and it sounds like you are trying to use `role` instead...perhaps you have `role` in one place and `roles` in the other?

Comment: I edited Rooneyl's code. It now has `role` instead of `roles`. It works for me. I already tested it.

Comment: @Rooneyl how to do that if you're using FOSUserBundle? Pls badly need help.

Answer (score 19):

You can do it in your form.

Make a service for your form

```
app.form.type.task:
    class: AppBundle\Form\FormType
    arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

In your FormType, add a constructor to get your service.

```
private $authorization;
public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker)
{
    $this->authorization = $authorizationChecker;
}
```

Then, in your builder, you will be able to check user permission

```
$builder->add('foo');
if($this->authorization->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
{
   $builder->add('bar');
}
```

And then, finally, you can render your form

```
{% if form.formbar is defined %}
    {{ form_row(form.formbar ) }}
{% endif %}
```

Please note that it mean that your field may be null. Because maybe you want to see some of them visible by some users and others not.

Else, you can set a default value in your entity construct method, to make sure value won't be null if user don't/can't fill it.

Comment: Simply great. Thanks