# Symfony inject Voters into Form Types

Tags: php, symfony

Hi i'm trying to access my voters inside my UserType. I tried to follow the elegant second answer (Bart Bartoman) in this subject [How to customize form field based on user roles in Symfony2/3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433295/how-to-customize-form-field-based-on-user-roles-in-symfony2-3)

I got this error
`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to PortalBundle\Form\UserType::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker, none given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 92`

```
portal.security.form.user:
        class: PortalBundle\Form\FormType
        arguments: ['@security.authorization_checker']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

The beginning of my UserType.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    private $authorization;
    public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorization = $authorizationChecker;
    }
```

This is how I call this from the controller
`$editForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);`

I'm using symfony 3.4

EDIT: Added my security.yml

```
services:
    hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.default:
        class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Http\ResourceOwnerMap
        arguments: ["@security.http_utils", ['default'], ['default']]
    security.user.provider.guardd:
        class: Potf\SecurityBundle\Security\Core\User\GuarddMockUserProvider
    security.user.provider.guardd.user:
        abstract: true
        public: false
        class: Potf\SecurityBundle\Security\Core\User\GuarddUser

hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [default]
    resource_owners:
        guardd:
            type:              oauth2
            client_id:         default
            client_secret:     default
            access_token_url:  default
            authorization_url: default
            infos_url:         default
            paths:
                identifier: identifier
                nickname:   nickname
                realname:   realname

security:
    encoders:
        Potf\SecurityBundle\Security\Core\User\GuarddUser: plaintext

    providers:
        in_memory:
            guardd:
                users:
                    user:
                        email: user
                        password: user
                        fullname: user
                        access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJmdWxsbmFtZSI6IlVzZXIiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJleHAiOjMzMDQyMTY0MDcxLCJpYXQiOjE0ODUyNTUyNzF9.LQU1NV8FMZGH9b3r7Rn4BrPK5Qany6ym_EyA9MMteImlDrjAs45vIvr0BLKsU4N7isvGGRDc_MXphWUm6pM61LMVTcFOGmlERd1B2BEmWkkDVTKEy5jBu7vOVHqK5LYLseAB4K3Qxk17cDe80uO1vutbeb0syWykuspHuWunr_tTqoot70jYCEmbhvT_4jsxnxowpsoL13iIkkqGdtdLjxTQ5RQE5sjhXnguiHDeC4Fhm1-gsptQmCp00yzdq9GcPFurddtP_MWNjX4NwqhuZjiIVeQqG154ocbF_Z49a6aj2tLsNY_vpinaCcwvNL5Yshg1n96q4JrQZM4U0ysrWE1oPMI887rhHBilwrtk1l1Z5czUH8zVLMzeAzSMr0MvidjM01nKidbbVJBXmaACoyqcftFNAG7_CZijW2oYlZe7UiJ71cpvrxzOr1Tlpgs4YmvxRC4bIwijdI_QJXwDmL4Q-JfRfAu14g9JigEoCHLV-oU56D_e2Btd3X4uL7EII-F--0LKcuFcb1_eK8GTvcECz7rRA5Phpv0Hi4kxJfIQtKFvOnJ3W0JA0X5d_-x2Jn__TdAHrZIVYWChnWKFw2tv7UuQ9ymGoUiq7qH0OSPmFr7DMQtudFE7bszyaK1X_wVhHSFej82HVqL_SVC4epEle5_53xrJC5IuTIgl0sE"
                        actions:
                            - { type: generic, name: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
                    manager:
                        email: manager
                        password: manager
                        fullname: Manager
                        access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJmdWxsbmFtZSI6Ik1hbmFnZXIiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1hbmFnZXIiLCJleHAiOjMzMDQyMTY0MzcyLCJpYXQiOjE0ODUyNTU1NzJ9.rtTQ_AK8ZQjJ5LdCSefZrKSiG86hcmpugENHfAXY1vZPvnLQPHSwTqYQbiUkCvoA91Y0CqJpocYFIMVTGGlWLWmjhf7xpuDxUPz2jXvBuvBcITcnPRCBrFh-zxuWoIefrhTm6xxGU8xGLam_ld5WRuxtZeT8DrXSI-g1Ux7YXELJ5HYbvoft6qHYCE85lvjfPJMUGT-A8ig4ycStP-Rn4SIuowqWw5Ap_he-YqsrGv8G8zao_QiyDcvJAqdxCTv8Ts6Pqpa_LFu-Qk1wqqOFv1jRTlwoeUS72FqWmBAhxz8EH1azGMS89xGoVfBOUpWCL6hIS2ossWeFTG2qi2yPRD8Ian8O7hdxo2WKj0AgSlFtzyopHkQ48XQtTq1RWAQvFyt66Pwr4HUh51-lV8UE8q-J2YkW8k06bPLCWCURUe_8-ATDEbDi89A4i3Nv5fyiRJF4OAGR70JWGFmLjx-ASDyh1XuquBNW3aYOodHHPfpIIUEOsEtlZFkyIgDqtDu1D2aMAWNGwVzMpRh0R6pwSn1f_pb_55bq7HyTWSdY1BDC1ZvmLnp-FAjz3ZxQhgvCR79QyMsY1PTAuNeFnALQvoQ6tm_aOZ0dQOblAi3YQAJLL1QcU-Hhf5thtkZ9lDYriEfN69LvPwtvTpWwpymMhJeeGsWwpN4c100r_IM2mnE"
                        actions:
                            - { type: generic, name: 'ROLE_MANAGER' }
                    invalid:
                        email: invalid
                        password: invalid
                        fullname: invalid

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            security:   false

        api_doc:
            pattern:    ^/api/doc
            security:   false

        api_exchange:
            pattern:    ^/api/exchange/
            security:   false

        api_area:
            pattern:    ^/api((?!/auth/user).)
            stateless:  true
            guard:
                entry_point: potf_security.guard.jwt
                authenticators:
                    - potf_security.guard.jwt
                    - potf_security.guard.oauth

        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: guardd_mock_login
                check_path: guardd_mock_login_check
            logout:
                path: logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: The form factory always looks up form types in the container by class names.  So change portal.security.form.user to PortalBundle\Form\FormType and get rid of the class attribute as well as the form tag.  I might add that with autowire enabled, you won't need a service definition at all.  But you can save that step for later.

Comment: I will implement that next. Sounds great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: It turns out it was a definition problem in the config file.

But the answer below should still be useful if you're facing a problem when autowiring the `AuthorizationChecker` class.

---

Use the interface instead:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorization = $authorizationChecker;
    }
```

You also need the `symfony/security-bundle` in your `composer.json`. `symfony/security` is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got this error `Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to PortalBundle\Form\UserType::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface, none given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and defined" at /var/www/html/src/PortalBundle/Form/UserType.php line 25` on the construct parameter. I already have symfony/security-bundle.

Comment: There is something wrong with your yaml config. Are you sure it is correctly imported ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I added the security.yml in the post, it is imported in my parameters.yml

Comment: Where is the `portal.security.form.user` definition ?

Comment: Yeah that was just a definition problem, sorry. Thanks once again!

Comment: @fxbt Consider updating your answer to make it clear that service definition id was the problem, not the interface.  Otherwise it will be confusing for future developers who might read this.